# Group data by multiple columns

Tags: crystal-reports

My SQL query needs to return data grouped by requirement. To do so, it needs to group by more than one column.

Example SQL:

```
SELECT 
      [MainMenu],
      [Submenu1],
      [Submenu2],
      [Submenu3],
      [Submenu4],
      [Submenu5],
      [Submenu6],
      [Submenu7],
      Sum([MainMenuReturn]) AS "Total Returns",
      [ExitReason]
  FROM [dbo].[Custom_IVRMenuUsage]
GROUP BY MainMenu,Submenu1,Submenu2,Submenu3,Submenu4,Submenu5,Submenu6,Submenu7,ExitReason
```

This will return each combination of the groupings and keep the column separated data. I cannot do this in Crystal. If I concatenate the columns into one field to group by, I lose the ability to keep the data separated into their columns for formatting.

How can I accomplish this in Crystal without writing a separate stored procedure?

Comment: May you explain the desired output? I did not get it.

Comment: Have you tried writing a formula that combines all those individual fields into a single string? You could then make a group in your report that sorts based on `@MassiveStringIJustMade`

Comment: I did, initially, create one field that concatenated all the fields into one field to group on. The data came back as I needed; however, it comes back as one field on the report and you cannot format the individual columns. The sql code above, will return the data the same way, but it keeps the columns in tact and the data is in those individual columns when returned. Hope this explains it and I'll post a data set next from the SQL code above to help illustrate.

Comment: Sorry, the data set won't format correctly in the response window